# Reliable way to programmatically get the number of hardware threads on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

I'm struggling to find a reliable way to get the number of hardware threads on Windows. I am running a Windows 7 Professional SP1 64-bit on a machine with dual CPU Intel Xeon E5-2699 v3 @ 2.30GHz totalizing 36 cores and 72 threads.
I have tried different methods to get the number of cores, and I have found that only two of them seem to work accurately in a 32-bit or 64-bit process. Here are my results:

```
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
|                    Methods                     | 32-bit process | 64-bit process |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
| GetSystemInfo->dwNumberOfProcessors            |             32 |             36 |
| GetNativeSystemInfo->dwNumberOfProcessors      |             36 |             36 |
| GetLogicalProcessorInformation                 |             36 |             36 |
| GetProcessAffinityMask.processAffinityMask     |             32 |             32 |
| GetProcessAffinityMask.systemAffinityMask      |             32 |             32 |
| omp_get_num_procs                              |             32 |             36 |
| getenv("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS")                 |             36 |             36 |
| GetActiveProcessorCount(ALL_PROCESSOR_GROUPS)  |             64 |             72 |
| GetMaximumProcessorCount(ALL_PROCESSOR_GROUPS) |             64 |             72 |
| boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()          |             32 |             36 |
| Performance counter API                        |             36 |             36 |
| WMI                                            |             72 |             72 |
| HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor   |             72 |             72 |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I do not explain why all these functions return different values. The only 2 methods which seem reliable to me is either using WMI (but fairly complicated) or simply to read in the Windows registry the following key: HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor.

What do you think?
Do you confirm that the WMI and registry key methods are the only reliable methods?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You get however many you can effectively use in your program.  Sure, WMI is never the wrong way to do this.

Answer (score 9):

The API function that you need is `GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx`. Since you have more than 64 processors, your processors are grouped. `GetLogicalProcessorInformation` only reports the processors in the processor group that the thread is currently assigned. You need to use `GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx` to get past that limitation.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683194.aspx) says:

> On systems with more than 64 logical processors, the GetLogicalProcessorInformation function retrieves logical processor information about processors in the processor group to which the calling thread is currently assigned. Use the GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx function to retrieve information about processors in all processor groups on the system.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer with code:

```
size_t myHardwareConcurrency(){
    size_t concurrency=0;
    DWORD length=0;
    if(GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx(RelationAll,nullptr,&length)!=FALSE){
        return concurrency;}
    if(GetLastError()!=ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER){
        return concurrency;}
    std::unique_ptr<void,void(*)(void*)>buffer(std::malloc(length),std::free);
    if(!buffer){
        return concurrency;}
    unsigned char*mem=reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buffer.get());
    if(GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx(RelationAll,reinterpret_cast<PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX>(mem),&length)==false){
        return concurrency;}
    for(DWORD i=0;i<length;){
        auto*proc=reinterpret_cast<PSYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION_EX>(mem+i);
        if(proc->Relationship==RelationProcessorCore){
            for(WORD group=0;group<proc->Processor.GroupCount;++group){
                for(KAFFINITY mask=proc->Processor.GroupMask[group].Mask;mask!=0;mask>>=1){
                    concurrency+=mask&1;}}}
        i+=proc->Size;}
    return concurrency;}
```

It worked on my dual Xeon gold 6154 with Windows 64 bit system (2 procs * 18 cores/proc * 2 threads/core = 72 threads). The result is 72 both for 32 bit processes and for 64 bit processes.

I do not have access to a system with a 32 bit Windows though.

In case of error, it returns zero like `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` does.

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlogicalprocessorinformationex#remarks) you would just need to count the number of occurrences of `RelationProcessorCore` so the counting loop can be simplified to: `if (proc->Relationship==RelationProcessorCore) ++concurrency;`. This is because the number of groups a core belongs to is always 1 and the mask only contains a single bit denoting the position (or affinity) in that group. I guess it would also make counting under WoW64 emulation more robust...

Comment: @klaustriendl I just edited the OP question to make a clear distinction between number of cores and number of threads. Although he used the word cores all along, the number he gave were for the number of hardware threads. Your suggestion would be correct to get the number of core, but the OP wanted the number of threads.

Comment: Thx @Arnaud Still you wouldn't have to loop through the groups as the group count is always 1. Anyway, to me the "number of active processor cores" was equivalent to the "number of logical processors", but reading further on `PROCESSOR_RELATIONSHIP` I understand that a core can have more than 1 logical processor. What happens under Wow64? Is the mask for logical processors 32 through 63 correct? Because the remarks state that it's incorrectly represented as duplicates for 0-31... (I guess for your specific machine these would be logical processors 32-35 of cores number 17+18?

Comment: @klaustriendl On my machine (6 cores 12 threads 3930K), in x64 mode `proc->Processor.GroupMask[0].Mask` is 3 and I need to add 2 for each `RelationProcessorCore`

Comment: What do you mean exactly by x64 mode? Is it the 32-bit executable on a 64-bit OS, i.e. WoW64?

Comment: I compile this code with VS 2017 and I have "x64" or "Win32". I am not sure how the OS runs my executable though. About the number of group, it is not guaranteed to be 1. I developped this code for a machine with 2 processors * 18 cores per proc * 2 threads per core =  72 threads and on this machine, the number of group is 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183615/discussion-between-klaus-triendl-and-arnaud).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CPUID instruction to query the processor directly (platform independent, though since you can't do inline asm in MSVC anymore for some compilers you'll need to use different functions to have access to it). The only downside is that as of a few years ago Intel and AMD handle this instruction differently, and you'll need to do a lot of work to ensure you are reading the information correctly. In fact, not only will you be able to get a core count, but you can get all kinds of processor topology information. Not sure how it works in a VM though if you are using that environment.

Comment: CPUID is hardly platform independent. You yourself note that it doesn't always behave right, and you completely ignore other processors like ARM.